# SSH or FTP into Cisco router

Tags: router, ssh, ftp

I am trying to find a way to SSH or FTP (some way I can get "inside and manage the internal files") into my Cisco router. The model is **E1000**. Thank you.

Comment: Title is a little misleading, may want to refer to Linksys instead. The standard way to manage "internal files" on a Cisco router is from the CLI itself e.g. `delete flash:/vlan.dat`

Comment: Could you please mark this as answered?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.abcarticledirectory.com/Article/How-to-Configure-SSH--Secure-Shell--for-Remote-Login-on-a-Cisco-Router/198006

You have to have security software installed from Cisco for SSH to function.  As for FTP, this page may help:

http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/wireless/linksys/E1000

Comment: For the first link you showed me, it just shows commands. Where do I type these commands?

Comment: I pointed out the website to show "You have to have security software installed from Cisco for SSH to function" concept.  If you go to the second website (Linksys website for the E1000) it shows use of proprietary software to connect to the router.  If there are no settings in that software to turn on SSH you may want to ask a Linksys tech (you can chat with them at the second URL provided) how to do it.